# Add or remove multiple horizontal lines in Shinly ggplot2

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have a shiny app that plots the data from an upload file. I have couple of `checkboxInput` & couple of corresponding `numericInput` in the app. Plotting works fine with `numericInputs`, as in below simple reproducible example. What I want to achieve here is, be able to select or deselect that specific checkbox so that `geom_hline` is added or removed from the plot.

**Users can select or deselect one or multiple at a time based on the requirement.**

**Thanks in advance**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "H Line Plot Add & Remove"),
  dashboardSidebar(checkboxInput("minthresh", "Mimimun Threshold", T),
                   numericInput("minthreshvalue", "Minimum Threshold Value:", min = 0, max = 9, value = 5),

                   checkboxInput("maxthresh", "Maximun Threshold", T),
                   numericInput("maxthreshvalue", "Maximum Threshold Value:", min = 0, max = 9, value = 6),

                   checkboxInput("optthresh", "Optimal Threshold", T),
                   numericInput("optthreshvalue", "Optimal Threshold Value:", min = 0, max = 9, value = 7)),
  dashboardBody(plotOutput("plot1"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- iris

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = input$minthreshvalue), color = "red", size = 3) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = input$maxthreshvalue), color = "blue", size = 3) +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept = input$optthreshvalue), color = "darkgreen", size = 3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `server` code to conditionally display the horizontal lines based on corresponding checkbox input values.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- iris
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20)) +
      geom_boxplot() 
    if (input$minthresh) {
      p <- p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = input$minthreshvalue), color = "red", size = 3)
    }
    if (input$maxthresh) {
      p <- p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = input$maxthreshvalue), color = "blue", size = 3)
    }
    if (input$optthresh) {
      p <- p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = input$optthreshvalue), color = "darkgreen", size = 3)
    }
    p
  })
}
```

[image]